# Add dash line from Widget to Widget in a custom manner

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this UI given to me [Fig: Custom UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bi0k.png). I have multiple widget as a cardview or it can be in container does not matter much. Issue is i am unable to figure out how to achive the connected line shown in the image.

Should i manually add widget as a line similar to divider? Then how its gonna update itself when dynamic value comes into play and my UI changes its height? Is there anyway to connect widget's left center point to another widgets left center point similar to the image provided?

Comment: you should use `CustomPsint` widget to draw the connection lines

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will do some digging in CustomPaint and see where it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be my solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final double padding = 15;
  final List<GlobalKey> keys = [];
  GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>> nameCardKey = GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>>(debugLabel: 'nameCard');
  GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>> titleHolderCardKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'holderCard');
  GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>> futureOwnersCardKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'futureCard');
  GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>> mainTitleCardKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'mainCard');
  GlobalKey<State<MyHomePage>> lineKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'line');
  final List<Offset?> offsets = [];

  void getOffsets() {
    keys.addAll([nameCardKey, titleHolderCardKey, futureOwnersCardKey, mainTitleCardKey, lineKey]);
    for (GlobalKey key in keys) {
        if (key.currentContext != null || offsets.length > 6) {
          offsets.add((key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).localToGlobal(Offset.zero));
        }
    }
    print(offsets);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getOffsets();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
       
        body: Stack(
          children: [
             if (offsets.length >= 4) ...[
               CustomPaint(
                    size: Size.infinite,
                    painter: LinesPainter(
                      Offset(offsets[0]!.dx, offsets[0]!.dy),
                      Offset(offsets[0]!.dx, offsets[2]!.dy)
                    ),
                  ),
               CustomPaint(
                    size: Size.infinite,
                    painter: LinesPainter(
                      Offset(offsets[1]!.dx - 2* padding, offsets[1]!.dy),
                      Offset(offsets[3]!.dx, offsets[3]!.dy)
                    ),
                  ),
               CustomPaint(
                    size: Size.infinite,
                    painter: LinesPainter(
                      Offset(offsets[2]!.dx - 2* padding, offsets[2]!.dy - 20),
                      Offset(offsets[3]!.dx, offsets[3]!.dy + 120)
                    ),
                  ),
            ],
         
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Card(
                    key: nameCardKey,
                    child: SizedBox(height: 40, width: 250, child: Text('some name i guess')),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                key: titleHolderCardKey,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 250,
                                  child: Text('title'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 40,
                              ),
                              Card(
                                key: futureOwnersCardKey,
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 60,
                                  width: 250,
                                  child: Text('future owners'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          key: mainTitleCardKey,
                          child: SizedBox(height: 200, width: 250, child: Text('title')),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
                  
          ],
        ) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
  }
}

class LinesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset? start, end;

  LinesPainter(this.start, this.end);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (start == null || end == null) return;
    canvas.drawLine(
        start!,
        end!,
        Paint()
          ..strokeWidth = 2
          ..color = Colors.grey);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(LinesPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.start != start || oldDelegate.end != end;
  }
}
```

Here you wait until all elements are rendered, then in the next frame you get context of every element. From this context you can get coordinates, adjust coordinates to additional paddings, card/container sizes to get most straight lines possible et voila!

Along with object's context you can get it's size & other parameters to base your alignment changes on.

Put the if statement to the bottom of the stack to see exactly how lines are being laid, when you're done just put the if at the top to get lines covered by the cards to get the "connected elements" look.

The result being something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I needed to change values to adjust to my UI. I suppose, depending on where I put my view, I also need to change the values.